# STM32 SPI communication with HAL

Tags: embedded, stm32, spi, stm32f4discovery, hal

I just started programming a STM32 and generated a code with CubeMX for an SPI communcation with a gyroscope (L3GD20)
I have a problem with the HAL_SPI commands.

I first try to read the `WHO_AM_I` register which return a good response (0xD4)
Then I tried to do the same with `CTRL_REG1` register and it was still good by returning (0x07).

But if I try to get both of them one after the other, the `HAL_SPI_Receive` keeps sending the data of the first `HAL_SPI_Transmit` of the code...
Tried to give it other buffers but still didn't work.

Here is the part of the code I'm intersted in :

```
    uint8_t txData[8],rxData[8];    //Buffers for the first read.
    uint8_t rBuffer[8];             //Buffer for the second read.
/*...............................................................
 *...............................................................
 *...............................................................
*/...............................................................
  txData[0] = ADDR_WHO_AM_I | 0x80; 
  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2, txData, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi2, rxData, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);   //Returns the right value
  HAL_Delay(1000);

  txData[0] = ADDR_CTRL_REG1 | 0x80;
  HAL_Delay(500);
  
  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2, txData, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi2, rBuffer, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);  //Returns the same value...
  HAL_Delay(1000);
```

PS : I also would like to know more about `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive` if possible, how should I use it to perform the same task ? (Reading 1 byte from different registers).

There is the full code too :

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under Ultimate Liberty license
  * SLA0044, the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with
  * the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                             www.st.com/SLA0044
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

//      Gyro Definitions
#define ADDR_WHO_AM_I   0x0f
#define ADDR_CTRL_REG1  0x20
#define ADDR_CTRL_REG2  0x21
#define ADDR_CTRL_REG3  0x22
#define ADDR_CTRL_REG4  0x23
#define ADDR_CTRL_REG5  0x24
#define ADDR_OUT_TEMP   0x26
#define ADDR_STATUS_REG 0x27
#define ADDR_OUT_X_L    0x28
#define ADDR_OUT_X_H    0x29
#define ADDR_OUT_Y_L    0x2A
#define ADDR_OUT_Y_H    0x2B
#define ADDR_OUT_Z_L    0x2C
#define ADDR_OUT_Z_H    0x2D


/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c3;

SD_HandleTypeDef hsd1;

SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
HAL_SD_CardInfoTypeDef pCardInfo;
char datar[1024];
HAL_StatusTypeDef retstat;

//HAL_MMC_CardInfoTypeDef pCardInfo;
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_SDMMC1_SD_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C3_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI2_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */
    int ret;
    uint8_t txData[8],rxData[8];    //Buffers for the first read.
    uint8_t rBuffer[8];             //Buffer for the second read.
    
  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SDMMC1_SD_Init();
  MX_I2C3_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  

  txData[0] = ADDR_WHO_AM_I | 0x80; 
  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2, txData, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi2, rxData, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  HAL_Delay(1000);

  txData[0] = ADDR_CTRL_REG1 | 0x80;
  HAL_Delay(500);
  
  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2, txData, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi2, rBuffer, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  HAL_Delay(1000);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */  
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 10;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV7;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_I2C3|RCC_PERIPHCLK_SDMMC1;
  PeriphClkInit.I2c3ClockSelection = RCC_I2C3CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
  PeriphClkInit.Sdmmc1ClockSelection = RCC_SDMMC1CLKSOURCE_PLL;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief I2C3 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2C3_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C3_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C3_Init 1 */
  hi2c3.Instance = I2C3;
  hi2c3.Init.Timing = 0x10909CEC;
  hi2c3.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c3.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c3.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c3.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c3.Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
  hi2c3.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c3.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Analogue filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c3, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Digital filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c3, 0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C3_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C3_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief SDMMC1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SDMMC1_SD_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDMMC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SDMMC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDMMC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SDMMC1_Init 1 */
  hsd1.Instance = SDMMC1;
  hsd1.Init.ClockEdge = SDMMC_CLOCK_EDGE_RISING;
  hsd1.Init.ClockBypass = SDMMC_CLOCK_BYPASS_DISABLE;
  hsd1.Init.ClockPowerSave = SDMMC_CLOCK_POWER_SAVE_DISABLE;
  hsd1.Init.BusWide = SDMMC_BUS_WIDE_1B;
  hsd1.Init.HardwareFlowControl = SDMMC_HARDWARE_FLOW_CONTROL_ENABLE;
  hsd1.Init.ClockDiv = 0;
  if (HAL_SD_Init(&hsd1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_SD_ConfigWideBusOperation(&hsd1, SDMMC_BUS_WIDE_4B) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDMMC1_Init 2 */

    //HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_MMC_GetCardInfo(MMC_HandleTypeDef *hmmc, HAL_MMC_CardInfoTypeDef *pCardInfo)
  /* USER CODE END SDMMC1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief SPI2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SPI2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 1 */
  /* SPI2 parameter configuration*/
  hspi2.Instance = SPI2;
  hspi2.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi2.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi2.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;
  hspi2.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_HARD_OUTPUT;
  hspi2.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_8;
  hspi2.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi2.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  hspi2.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
  hspi2.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PE1 PE0 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_0;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Comment: Does it make sense for the device to receive and transmit? That's all about reading the datasheet of that device. Normal SPI _transceives_, it sends and transmits at the same time, full duplex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't explain the behavior you described for the separate HAL_SPI_Transmit() and HAL_SPI_Receive() calls.  But regardless, you should be using HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive().  Here is an example.

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef ReadRegister(uint8_t addr, uint8_t *byte)
{
    HAL_StatusTypeDef hal_status;
    uint8_t tx_data[2];
    uint8_t rx_data[2];
    
    tx_data[0] = addr | 0x80;  // read operation
    tx_data[1] = 0;            // dummy byte for response
    
    hal_status = HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi2, tx_data, rx_data, 2, SPI_TIMEOUT);
    
    if (hal_status == HAL_OK)
    {
        *byte = rx_data[1];    // response is in the second byte
    }
    return hal_status;
}
```

The master SPI controller clocks out bytes and both the master and slave transmit and receive during each byte.  For the first byte, the master transmits the register addr and the slave transmits a dummy byte because the slave doesn't know what register you're trying to read yet.  (Some slave devices send a status in the first byte.)  For the second byte, the master transmits a dummy byte for the purpose of generating more clocks on which the slave can respond.  After receiving the register address during the first byte, the slave knows which register value to transmit during the second byte.  Notice in the example code that the received byte you're interested in is the second byte of the response buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Since `HAL_SPI_Receive` is already using `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive` [(github stm32f4 spi driver)](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF4/blob/master/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_spi.c#L948) to send dummy data to generate clock,  you can use that fact and ditch the `HAL_SPI_Transmit`, and use the receive function like this:

```
  rxData[0] = ADDR_WHO_AM_I | 0x80; 
  HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi2, rxData, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
```

Note that we provide the address and operation using rxData but it will effectively be overwritten by the read data.

or you can simply use `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive` :

```
  txData[0] = ADDR_WHO_AM_I | 0x80; 
  HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi2, txData, rxData, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  
  HAL_Delay(500);
  
  txData[0] = ADDR_CTRL_REG1 | 0x80; 
  HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi2, txData, rxData, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
```

Comment: Size = 1 is not enough.  The device likely sends dummy or status data in the first byte because it doesn't know which register value to return until after it has received the register address in the first byte.  So size = 2 is required to read the register value.

Comment: the receive part of  HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive function happens after sending the first byte, and since the MCU here is master, and the datasheet clearly states that the data out from the sensor is latched starting from the 9th clock pulse, and we are only reading 1 byte of data, then 1 byte as size is enough, note that the size parameter in HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive doesnt mean sizeof(tx+rx) , rather the same for both: so 1 byte for the mode and address (tx) and 1 byte for the slave data (rx), check lines 1185 and 1188  of the github link.

Comment: Look at the while loop starting on line 1264.  The loop both transmits and receives one byte (and decrements both counters) each time through the loop.  SPI is full duplex and this is only 8 clock pulses per loop.  You have to transmit a second dummy byte in order to get the 9th through 16th clock pulses.